# Error when deleting pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a packet structure which looks similar to this:

```
struct packet {
    sockaddr_in m_Recv;
    int m_iPacketSize;
    unsigned char* m_ucpPacket;
}
```

This is a selection of the code where I'm using this structure:

```
packet tOutPacket;
tOutPacket.m_Recv = tInPacket.m_Recv;
tOutPacket.m_iPacketSize = 256;
tOutPacket.m_ucpPacket = new unsigned char[256];

// Creating a uuid (not important how it's done, the pointer has 16 bytes)
unsigned char* uuid = NetworkHandlerN::ConnectionData::createUUID(hardware_hash);
NetworkHandlerN::PacketHandler::addUUIDToPacket(tOutPacket.m_ucpPacket, uuid);
delete[] uuid;

UDPsend(tOutPacket.m_Recv, tOutPacket.m_ucpPacket, tOutPacket.m_iPacketSize);

/* Delete pointer */
delete[] tOutPacket.m_ucpPacket; // This is causing an error
```

Here is my UDPsend method:

```
bool NBsocket::UDPsend(sockaddr_in& AddrSento, const unsigned char* cucpBuffer, int iSize)
{
    if(sendto(m_iSocket, reinterpret_cast<const char*>(cucpBuffer), iSize, 0, (sockaddr*) &AddrSento, sizeof(AddrSento)) == -1) {
        m_iErrorCode = 6;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Here is the addUUIDToPacket method:

```
static void addUUIDToPacket(unsigned char* ucpPacket, unsigned char* ucpChar) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < ciUUIDSize; i++) {
        ucpPacket[ciHeaderSize+i] = ucpChar[i];
    }
}
```

First I thought I deleted the pointer `tOutPacket.m_ucpPacket` somewhere but I checked that. and if I perform a test on the data stored inside like this (right before the `delete[]`):

```
if(tOutPacket.m_ucpPacket[tOutPacket.m_iPacketSize-1] == 0x08) 
    std::cout << "0x08";
```

It works perfectly fine (yes the value is supposed to be 0x08)

Here is my call stack output:

```
    ntdll.dll!77dcfadc()    Unknown
    [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll] 
    ntdll.dll!77db4f92()    Unknown
    ntdll.dll!77d926fc()    Unknown
    ntdll.dll!77dd0b37()    Unknown
    ntdll.dll!77d8a967()    Unknown
>   msvcp110.dll!std::_Fputc<char>(char _Byte, _iobuf * _File) Line 83  C++
    msvcp110.dll!std::basic_filebuf<char,std::char_traits<char> >::overflow(int _Meta) Line 383 C++
    msvcp110.dll!std::basic_streambuf<char,std::char_traits<char> >::xsputn(const char * _Ptr, __int64 _Count) Line 406 C++
```

I already tested a lot but couldn't figure out what was going wrong.

Hope someone can help me. If required I can add the `/* add data to packet */` part but that will be a little bit more code.

**EDIT**

Found the error. I passed a byte to this method:

```
static void addToPacket(unsigned char* ucpPacket, int iInt, int iPos) 
{
    ucpPacket[iPos+0] = iInt & 0xFF;
    ucpPacket[iPos+1] = iInt >> 8 & 0xFF;
    ucpPacket[iPos+2] = iInt >> 8 & 0xFF;
    ucpPacket[iPos+3] = iInt >> 8 & 0xFF;
}
```

which caused all the touble... too many method overloads :). Must have lost the overview.

Comment: Are you making copies of your `packet` objects?

Comment: Hard to say. Seems you have memory corruption somewhere. How about posting the code where you 'add data to the packet'.

Comment: Are you sure tOutPacket.m_ucpPacket is not already deleted? Your test doesn't prove much.

Comment: Is it possible to make `packet` `constructors` and `destructor` it makes memory management just a bit easier.

Comment: @ahenderson I already have I just didn't copy them since they didn't really contribute to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Before trying to actually find the bug and its cause, consider whether you have to use new[] and delete[].

1. Is the size fixed at 256? can you just put a regular array in your struct? It's not exactly that big.
2. Assuming not, can you use `std::vector<unsigned char>` ?
3. Failing that can you use `boost::shared_array<unsigned char>` ? You'll have to also put in the size as a separate element (e.g. iPacketSize). For this you will still call `new[]` but the `delete[]` will be taken care of. You will have to hold on to this `shared_array` object as long as you require the memory it uses.

What does `createUUID` do? It returns `unsigned char *` but who owns this memory?

At what point does the data you send get copied? At the call `sendto` ?

Comment: Solved but in order to answer your questions: 1. no 2. I could 3. sounds interesting. creatuuid creates a uuid and returns a pointer owned by the calling method. (might change that so that the calling method has to pass the pointer which gets filled or reference it).